# How to center text on circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I use the d3 chord diagram example of [Andrew](http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewRP/7468330) and want to center all text labels within the curved slice. I tried many things but was never able to center the texts. Do you know what wizzard trick there is needed?

[image]

```
var width = 720,
height = 720,
outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10,
innerRadius = outerRadius - 24;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(innerRadius)
.outerRadius(outerRadius);

var layout = d3.layout.chord()
.padding(.04)
.sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
.sortChords(d3.ascending);

var path = d3.svg.chord()
.radius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("id", "circle")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
.attr("r", outerRadius);

d3.csv("ex_csv.csv", function(cities) {
d3.json("ex_json.json", function(matrix) {

// Compute the chord layout.
layout.matrix(matrix);

// Add a group per neighborhood.
var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
.data(layout.groups)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "group")
.on("mouseover", mouseover);


// Add the group arc.
var groupPath = group.append("path")
.attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + i; })
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return cities[i].color; });

// Add a text label.
var groupText = group.append("text")
.attr("x", 6)
.attr("dy", 15);

groupText.append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#group" + i; })
.text(function(d, i) { return cities[i].name; });

// Remove the labels that don't fit. :(
groupText.filter(function(d, i) { return groupPath[0][i].getTotalLength() / 2 - 16 < this.getComputedTextLength(); })
.remove();

// Add the chords.
var chord = svg.selectAll(".chord")
.data(layout.chords)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "chord")
.style("fill", function(d) { return cities[d.source.index].color; })
.attr("d", path);


}
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As an aside, I would suggest looking to upgrade to v4, documentation for v2 is nearly non-existent and is very hard to help with.*

You can set both the `text-anchor` and the  `startOffset` property to achieve what you are looking for.

First, you'll want to set `text-anchor` to `middle` as it is easier to specify the middle point than to find the middle point and work back to find where the text should start.

Second you'll need to set a `startOffset`. Note that if you use 50%, the text will not appear where you want, as the total length of the text path is all sides of the closed loop (chord anchor) you are appending to. Setting it to 25 % would work if you did not have a different outer and inner radius. But, as you have an outer radius that is 24 pixels greater than the inner radius you can try something like this to calculate the number of pixels you need to offset the center of the text:

```
groupText.append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#group" + i; })
.text(function(d, i) { return cities[i].name; })
.attr("startOffset",function(d,i) { return (groupPath[0][i].getTotalLength() - 48) / 4 })
.style("text-anchor","middle");
```

I subtract 48 because the sides of the anchor are 24 pixels each (the difference in the radii). I divide by four because the path doubles back on itself. If it was a general line I would just divide by two.

This approach is a little simplistic as the outer circumference is not the same as the inner circumference of each chord anchor, so I am off by a little bit, but it should be workable.

For labels that are on the cusp of being displayed, this will be awkward: the inner radius is shorter, so the formula for deteriming if a string is short enough to be displayed may be wrong - which may lead to some characters climbing up the side of the anchor (your example also 16 pixels as the difference in radii to calculate if text is too long, rather than 24).

This is the end result:

[image]

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/bb2e6b55e6f649c283542261f35fc31b/) is a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

```
groupText
  .append("textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#group" + i; })
  .text(function(d, i) { return cities[i].name; })
  .attr("startOffset",function(d,i) { return (groupPath[0][i].getTotalLength() - 48) / 4 })
  .style("text-anchor","middle");
```

I subtract 48 because the sides of the anchor are 24 pixels each (the difference in the radii). I divide by four because the path doubles back on itself. If it was a general line I would just divide by two.

This approach is a little simplistic as the outer circumference is not the same as the inner circumference of each chord anchor, so I am off by a little bit, but it should be workable.